# Unable to connect the cordova project with mobile

Tags: android, cordova, adb, command-prompt, android-sdk-manager

I'm working in Cordova project and there I like to run my project using the command

> Cordova run android

in command prompt window. And I have also enabled developer option and USB debugging option in mobile and connected the mobile through USB.

Now on running the command, I get the issue that

---

```
Checking Java JDK and Android SDK versions ANDROID_SDK_ROOT=undefined (recommended setting) ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Tommy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk (DEPRECATED) adb: Command failed with exit code ENOENT Error output: 'adb' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I set the path for ANDROID_HOME as `C:\Users\Tommy\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools`

And opened a new command prompt window and ran the command again but also I was unable to get this right.

Can anyone help me with a solution? Thanks in advance..!

Comment: is the adb command in your path? Does `adb devices`command find your phone?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the platform-tools directory to the **executable PATH environment variable**. I added a screenshot below as an example:

[image]

Or set using powershell:

```
C:\Users\Tommy>powershell
Windows PowerShell
Copyright (C) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

PS C:\Users\Tommy> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_HOME", "C:\Users\Tommy\AppData\Local\Android\sdk", "User")
PS C:\Users\Tommy> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_TOOLS", [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_HOME", "User") + "\tools", "User")
PS C:\Users\Tommy> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS", [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_HOME", "User") + "\platform-tools", "User")
PS C:\Users\Tommy> [Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("PATH", "User") + ";"  + [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_TOOLS", "User") + ";" + [Environment]::GetEnvironmentVariable("ANDROID_PLATFORM_TOOLS", "User"), "User")
```

Comment: Are you getting the same error code? What does `echo %PATH%` in the command prompt output for you?